# Windows gets stuck uninstalling display languages

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to clear up some room on my PC, and I've got a ton of languages installed that I want to uninstall, but every time I try it just sits here for a while:

[image]

Then (after a while) it gets stuck here:

[image]

Then it comes up saying "Uninstall Failed".

Are there any logs that I can check to see why it failed, or are there any other ways I can remove these languages?

I've tried this with multiple languages, one at a time, a few at a time, and the same thing happens every time.

Comment: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2483139

Comment: "Are there any logs what I can check to see why it failed" Have you checked Windows' Event Logs yet? Have you run an [sfc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) and/or [chkdsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK) scan yet?

Comment: I'll take a look at the event log now, see if I can see anything there that I can understand

Comment: Maybe related: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/def8c41f-6d43-428c-adf9-6989867f1f1a/cannot-remove-korean-language-pack-win-7-x64?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: That sounds like the same issue to me, I won't be home for about 11 hours but I'll give it a try when I get in, thanks.

Comment: So, did you ever look in the Event Log? Any errors related to the uninstall in there?

Comment: Yeah I've just taking a look now after reading that comment from Oliver, and I found it caused a "cbs error 0x80070490", just doing some reason on it now.

Comment: It's doing it now because more then likely you have a corrupt component in your WinSXS directory which is the component store unfortunately there isn't a way to repair the file since you don't have the DISM tool since your using Windows 7

Comment: It looks like I might be able to clean it up on windows 7, I'll give it a try and report back. http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/

Comment: I tried what that posted said, and Windows Update Cleanup has 1.77gb in it, but when I tried to clear it up, nothing happened. I redid Disc cleanup, and the 1.77gb was still there. I have the Windows 10 preview queued up, so I might install that then try again.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound, sound like you WinSxS repository may have become corrupted (or at least the files you need for uninstalling the languages properly). If that's the case, check you disks for corruption/errors, restore from an image backup, or reinstall and start over.  If you want to fix the WinSxS repository, you'll need another Windows 7 machine with all the same features and updates installed so that you can harvest files from its WinSxS and force them into yours (not easy or fun), and then run an SFC to repair the files using your now-fixes WinSxS repository.

Comment: I've had some issues recently with updates not installing for me, so if me upgrading to Windows 10 doesn't sort the issue I think I'll have to do a reformat. Either way, I'll post back what I end up doing.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a result of a flaw in the language back that causes a conflict with SearchIndexer.  I had to deal with my computer hanging and dragging for years, before I tracked it down to SearchIndexer entering an infinite loop of hard drive reads.  SI problem is caused by a flaw in the language pack that permits a buffer overflow that resets the loop in the search.

So I shut down SI for a month and had no problems while it was off... Then I re-enabled it and tried to remove the language packs to prevent it again. It hung the drive-read again, of course. I had to keep SI disabled until the language packs were uninstalled to avoid the lock/hang.

Comment: do disable, load services (windows menu, type 'services')

Sort by name, scroll down to Windows Search

double click it, set start up type to disabled, click stop, click OK

Answer (score 0):

One other way to do such task by running `LPKSETUP` in the command, it will starts the same program to maintain whatever lp.cabs on your windows. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Your Uninstaller v7](http://www.ursoftware.com/) to remove the unwanted languages from your Windows 7 PC. It's better than the stock Windows 7 install/uninstall facility.

Comment: Not sure this software can remove display languages... those are Windows components, not "regular" programs.

Comment: From memory, there's the **Advanced Uninstall** and **Autofix** options which can be used to remove corrupt components installed in a given PC.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline. In addition, please be careful posting links in answers of this nature—they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise. See the [help/behavior] for more information.